# Fetching linked list in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, data-structures, linked-list, hierarchical-data

I have a MySQL database table with this structure:

```
table
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    data ..
    next_id INT NULL
```

I need to fetch the data in order of the linked list.  For example, given this data:

```
 id | next_id
----+---------
  1 |       2
  2 |       4
  3 |       9
  4 |       3
  9 |    NULL
```

I need to fetch the rows for id=1, 2, 4, 3, 9, in that order.  How can I do this with a database query?  (I can do it on the client end.  I am curious if this can be done on the database side.  Thus, saying it's impossible is okay (given enough proof)).

It would be nice to have a termination point as well (e.g. stop after 10 fetches, or when some condition on the row turns true) but this is not a requirement (can be done on client side).  I (hope I) do not need to check for circular references.

Comment: Are you able to create additional index tables?
I am actually curious about the explain plan for the query that Bill suggests. It might not be that bad since it is always looking up on primary key. I am assuming that you will be providing the ID of the first node in your query. (otherwise, it will be brutal). 10 round trips would do it (I know, not what you asked). Temporary tables created in the query might do it, particularly if your result set it small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some brands of database (e.g. Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server) support extra SQL syntax to run "recursive queries" but MySQL does not support any such solution.

The problem you are describing is the same as representing a tree structure in a SQL database.  You just have a long, skinny tree.

There are several solutions for storing and fetching this kind of data structure from an RDBMS.  See some of the following questions:

- "[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/)"
- "[Is it possible to make a recursive SQL query ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query)"

---

Since you mention that you'd like to limit the "depth" returned by the query, you can achieve this while querying the list this way:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1
 LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON (t1.next_id = t2.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t3 ON (t2.next_id = t3.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t4 ON (t3.next_id = t4.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t5 ON (t4.next_id = t5.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t6 ON (t5.next_id = t6.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t7 ON (t6.next_id = t7.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t8 ON (t7.next_id = t8.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t9 ON (t8.next_id = t9.id)
 LEFT JOIN mytable t10 ON (t9.next_id = t10.id);
```

It'll perform like molasses, and the result will come back all on one row (per linked list), but you'll get the result.

Comment: The first link looks very interesting.  Sadly, I cannot change the database structure.  Can it be modified somehow to suit my needs?  If not, I'll wait to see if anyone else answers saying 'yes.'

Comment: Crazy SELECT there.  =]  I'll just say this is impossible to reasonably accomplish.  Thanks for your information!

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend a SELECT like that.  But you said you couldn't change the database structure--sometimes there's no other choice.

Answer (score 6):

If what you are trying to avoid is having several queries (one for each node) and you are able to add columns, then you could have a new column that links to the root node.  That way you can pull in all the data at once by the root id, but you will still have to sort the list (or tree) on the client side.

So in this is example you would have:

```
 id | next_id | root_id
----+---------+---------
  1 |       2 |       1
  2 |       4 |       1
  3 |       9 |       1
  4 |       3 |       1
  9 |    NULL |       1
```

Of course the disadvantage of this as opposed to traditional linked lists or trees is that the root cannot change without writing on an order of magnitude of O(n) where n is the number of nodes.  This is because you would have to update the root id for each node.  Fortunately though you should always be able to do this in a single update query unless you are dividing a list/tree in the middle.

Comment: This solution is quite great.

Comment: The disadvantage can be avoided by using a separate table listing all the linked lists with unique IDs. Then, each linked list item can refer to that ID to remember which linked list it's part of, in stead of the "root_id". Thus allowing you to change the "root" element freely.

Answer (score 3):

This is less a solution and more of a workaround but, for a linear list (rather than the tree Bill Karwin mentioned), it might be more efficient to use a sort column on your list. For example:

```
TABLE `schema`.`my_table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `order` INT,
    data ..,
    INDEX `ix_order` (`sort_order` ASC)
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM `schema`.`my_table` ORDER BY `order`;
```

This has the disadvantage of slower inserts (you have to reposition all sorted elements past the insertion point) but should be fast for retrieval because the order column is indexed.

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't change the database structure because other programs depended upon the structure.  Thanks for your input, though!

Comment: Ironically, this is the solution that the user started out with in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594408/insert-record-into-table-with-position-without-updating-all-the-records-position), which respondents said should be changed to the linked list style the OP is using in this question! It seems like storing arbitrary record order in a database is just a difficult problem...