# SQL. Query for aggregating certain dependent fields

Tags: sql

Sorry for the vague title, I didn't know how else to phrase this.

Suppose you have a table such as the following table of stops on a train and the distances between this stop and the next:

```
Stop         NextStop       Distance
------------------------------------
Middletown   Bloomsbury     101
Bloomsbury   Shanksville    36
Shanksville  New City       53
New City     Washington     339
Washington   Andover        48
```

The problem is to determine the distance between Stops X and Y.  So, for example, the distance between Middletown and Shanksville is 101+36=137.

Is there a way to do this with a single query?  (Ideally, I am looking for a way to iteratively go through the Stops column by using the NextStop field of the previous row as the key the next row, and then collecting their distances into a column.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, I think something like this might work:

```
Select sum(distance)
from train_stops
start with stop = 'Middletown'
connect by stop = prior  nextstop;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if there is a general SQL solution?

Comment: @Jake: Not sure. What DBMS are you using? Oracle is not the only one to support recursive queries, but the syntax might vary slightly from to the another.

Comment: I'm not tied to a particular implementation.  I mean, I was trying to solve this problem and it just seemed overkill to have multiple queries for each distance segment.  Perhaps my single-query approach is not correct.

Comment: @Jake: For a generic solution, see Portman's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query