# count number of replies to user comment

Tags: php, mysql

I got multilevel comment system, I store comments in mysql database table with such fields:

```
id
article_id
user_id
date
content
comment_id
```

Where comment_id is parent comment's id.

how can i count number of replies to user comments after some specific date for all articles?
e.g:

```
- comment1
-- comment1.1
--- comment1.1.1
-- comment1.2
-- comment1.3
--- comment1.3.1
```

if user posted comment1, i need query to return 5. If user posted comment 1.3 - return 1.

Comment: Wouldn't comment1's query return 3? 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3 are direct children of comment1.

Comment: This question may be useful reading, even though it is for Postgresql: [Is it possible to make a recursive SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query)

Comment: @Zack , my bad, for comment1 the return should be 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for some ideas. One simple approach is to store the path in the comment tree like you listed above and do a `LIKE` query. E.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE comment_path LIKE 'comment1.%'
```

You'll of course want an index on the `comment_path` column, which will be used as long as a `%` is only used on the end.

Comment: "LIKE" approach seems to be fast to implement, so i'll do it first. Thanks for the article link, i'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

if it is possible, you can change your data schema to Nested Sets. With this schema you can count the answers in every hierarchy with a simple addition/substraction. Unfortunately I know only good tutorials in German :-/ for example [this](http://www.klempert.de/nested_sets/).

Comment: The Nested Set Model is covered in [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html).

Comment: @WhiteFang34: The article is now gone there, but available on its author's site: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/