# Accessing hierarchical data via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a table Menu that has column id and parent. Can we use normal JDBC (no ORM) to load hierarchical data from the database? Can we have a generic solution for all databases?

Comment: What database is this? Support for SQL queries involving hierarchies vary across databases.

Comment: Surely you can. The ORM argument is a non-argument. ORMs uses "normal JDBC" under the covers. Do you have a constructive and technical programming question?

Comment: Currently, my application supports multiple kind of database. MySql, Oracle, PostgreSql and Sql server are main databases

Comment: So, your question is more SQL-based than JDBC-based? JDBC is just the SQL executor. You control the selected data using SQL.

Comment: Can we have a generic solution for this??? I mean we just use JDBC API

Comment: I found this link http://www.patentgenius.com/image/6845376-6.html. Just use JDBC API and resultSet to retrieve hierarchy data

Comment: JDBC is definitely generic for all DBs. You just have to write the proper SQLs and figure if a single SQL query is understood by all DBs. Again, JDBC is just the SQL executor.

Answer (score 2):

First, [design your database tables to store hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database). Secondly, use [recursive CTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query) (Common Table Expressions) to get the hierarchical data. Without any more information about the structure of your database tables, and the queries used, I do not think it is possible to give a more specific answer.

Note, that the queries eventually used across databases could be different (I haven't attempted verifying recursive CTE support across databases), even though recursive CTEs are a part of the SQL99 specification. So, there might be no generic SQL query, but there is certainly a generic approach that you can adopt.

Comment: I mean generic is generic solution, not generic sql query. It's algorithm to solve this. Thanks for your help Vineet :)

Comment: Read up on CTEs. You don't need an algorithm, if the database can do the job for you; all you need in a database model that is suitable for a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a relational database, and your schema represents it in a hierarchical way, then JDBC can extract it - assuming that you can write the appropriate queries.

I fear that there's nothing generic about.  You'll have to write those queries, load the results into objects or data structures, and pass them to your UI for rendering.

Comment: I think this link can help me solve this issue: http://www.patentgenius.com/image/6845376-6.html