# translate plpgsql recursive function back to pg8.1

Tags: postgresql, recursion, plpgsql

I have the following plpgsql function that does work great on pg 8.3 and above but I need to translate it back to a pg 8.1 database and I can't seam to get it right.

Any tips? I need to get rid of the "RETURN QUERY" as it was not yet introduced in 8.1...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION specie_children (specie_id INT, self BOOLEAN)
      RETURNS SETOF specie AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
      r specie%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
      IF self THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM specie WHERE specieid = specie_id;
      END IF;
      FOR r IN SELECT * FROM specie WHERE parent = specie_id
      LOOP
        RETURN NEXT r;
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM specie_children(r.specieid, FALSE);
      END LOOP;
      RETURN;
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

How do I translate this ?

Comment: Maybe with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108/is-it-possible-to-make-a-recursive-sql-query

Comment: You are aware that 8.1 is dead and unsupported? And 8.3 will be soon. You should really be moving on to a current version.

Comment: Just do with `specie_children` what you do already with `specie`. You could even use the same variable, because the type must match anyway.

Comment: I am aware of the support of PG db's... Erwin what do you mean here? I don't quit get it.

Comment: Use the same `LOOP` and `RETURN NEXT r` construct (nested). @maniek has spelled it out in his answer (he uses a separate record `r2` var for the loop), but it should really be obvious? (Edited, last part was wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM specie_children(r.specieid, FALSE);
```

could be rewritten as

```
for r2 in select * from specie_children(r.specieid, FALSE)
loop
    return next r2
end loop
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error:
set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Comment: @user87400: You have to call your function the way I display it in my example, with `SELECT * FROM ...`

Comment: WHOOPS, so thats was my problem after all ;-) thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick demo. Basically @maniek already provided the answer.

Test table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE specie(specieid int, parent int);
INSERT INTO specie VALUES
 (1,0), (2,0), (3,0)
,(11,1), (12,1), (13,1)
,(111,11), (112,11), (113,11);
```

Rewritten function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION specie_children (specie_id INT, self BOOLEAN)
  RETURNS SETOF specie AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   r specie%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
IF self THEN
   FOR r IN SELECT * FROM specie WHERE specieid = $1
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT r;
   END LOOP;
END IF;

FOR r IN SELECT * FROM specie WHERE parent = $1
LOOP
   RETURN NEXT r;
   FOR r IN SELECT * FROM specie_children(r.specieid, FALSE)
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT r;
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM specie_children (1, true);
```

Returns:

```
specieid | parent
---------+-------
1        | 0
11       | 1
111      | 11
112      | 11
113      | 11
12       | 1
13       | 1
```